# If $V$ is finite dimensional $\Longrightarrow \left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}$ is the subspace generated by $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let be $V$ a inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let be $S$ a
> subset of $V$. We define $S^{\perp}=\left \{ x \in V | \langle s,x\rangle=0  
>  \text{    ,  } \forall s\in S \right \}$. Prove that:
>
> 1. The subspace generated by $S$ is contained in $\left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}$
> 2. If $V$ is finite dimensional, $\Longrightarrow \left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}$ is the subspace generated by $S$

I've already proved 1 using the fact that the inner product is linear. But for 2 I'm not sure how can I use the fact that V is finite dimensional. Intuitively, it came to my mind this:

\begin{align*}
\dim(V)&=dim(S)+dim(S^{\perp})\\
&=\dim\left(\left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}\right)+\dim(S^{\perp})\\
\end{align*}

But, that is telling me that $S= \left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}$, but what I want is $\text{span}(S)=\left ( S^{\perp} \right )^{\perp}$. So how can I prove 2?

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is not a subspace of $V$, then $\dim S$ does not make sense. You already proved that for any *subset* $S$, ${\rm span}(S) \subseteq (S^\perp)^{\perp}$, ok. Now, observe that $$\dim {\rm span}(S)^\perp = \dim S^\perp \quad \mbox{and}\quad \dim {\rm span}(S) + \dim S^\perp = \dim V < +\infty.$$The second formula follows from the rank-nullity theorem applied to $V \ni v \mapsto \langle v, \cdot\rangle|_{{\rm span}(S)} \in {\rm span}(S)^*$, as having finite-dimension implies that $\dim {\rm span}(S)^* = \dim {\rm span}(S)$.

Then you know that ${\rm span}(S) \subseteq (S^\perp)^\perp$ and both of them have the same finite dimension. Then they have to be equal.

Comment: Thank you ver much! I've two questions please, the first is how do you know that $dim span(S)^{\perp}=dim S^{\perp}$? And my second question is, what does this notation means $span (S)^{*}$?

Comment: 1) because $S^\perp = {\rm span}(S)^\perp$ (check); 2) for any vector space $W$, $W^* =\{f:W\to V \mid f \mbox{ is linear}\}$.